# Meaning of 「同性から見たって良い女だろ?」

Tags: reading-comprehension, grammar

I tried to understand and translate, I can think of:

1. "She's a nice woman from the same sex, right?"
2. "Seeing from the same sex, she's a nice woman, right?"
3. "She's a nice woman to see from the same sex, right?"

But I'm not sure what is the correct meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

「同性から見たって良い女だろ」

「同性から」= 'From the same sex'

「見たって」= 'even seeing'

「良い女」= 'attractive woman'

「だろ？」= 'right?'

Literally, 'Even viewed from the same sex, she's an attractive woman, right?' More naturally, 'Even a girl's gotta admit she's hot, right?'